# Where are the people of Kahhori settled in America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021

In **What if ...?** season 2 episode 6 we see a new character "Kahhori" who is from a tribe a settled somewhere in America.

What is the location of the place where the tribal people of her tribe are settled?

Is it based on a real location or a hypothetical one like Wakanda?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She was a member of the [Haudenosaunee Confederacy](https://www.haudenosauneeconfederacy.com/), in the Akwesasne region which is now upstate New York.

> As the characters speak in the Mohawk language, the episode is completely subtitled, and the story is informed by the history of the Akwesasne region in what is now upstate New York.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Walt Disney Company: How Marvel Studios’ ‘What If…?’ Created Kahhori, a New Mohawk Super Hero](https://thewaltdisneycompany.com/how-marvel-studios-what-if-created-kahhori-a-new-mohawk-super-hero/)</sup></sub>